# NodeJs and Mocha testing the response

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mocha.js

Is it possible to test the response from NodeJs using Mocha?

A GET request is made using $http from AngularJs to NodeJs. On success of the request this function is called:

```
var successCallback = function (data) {
    var SUCCESS_STATUS_CODE = 200;

    response.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    response.send({
        statusCode: SUCCESS_STATUS_CODE,
        data: data
    });
};
```

I have tried to use Sinon to spy on the function and also Mocha to check the request but I cannot get them to work. What is the best way to write a test to check that the output from "response.send"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test a response of a HTTP call from Node.JS, you could use [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent)

Create a folder and install inside mocha and superagent:

```
$ npm install superagent
$ npm install mocha
```

Then create a file called something like test.js with this code:

```
var request = require('superagent');
var assert = require('assert');

var URL = 'https://www.google.com.bo/#q=nodejs';

describe('Testing an HTTP Response', function () {

  it('should have a status code 200', function (done) {
    this.timeout(9000);

    request
      .get(URL)
      .end(function (err, response) {

        assert.equal(response.status, 200);
        done();

      });

  });

});
```

then you can run it with mocha

```
$ mocha
```